# How can i build custom softkeyboard for my android application?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, android-keypad

I developed an android application with custom softkey for input fields. It is working good for my xml input fields. I am not able to integrate it with facebook sharing login dialog box. I searched in google play there is lot of softkey board applications are designed. I installed one of that application and my device always invoking the newly installed application instead of default keyboard. I would like to do like that functionality for only my application. previously i followed the below link to build my custom keyboard which can be useful for only input fields which are designed by me not for facebook, twitter.

http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html

Please advice me to make the custom keyboard for entire application without regarding 3rd party app integration in our application.